# How to resolve CORS configuration ovh cloud?

Tags: reactjs, upload, strapi, aws-sdk-js, ovh

I want to upload a file to my bucket object storage on ovh cloud using s3.upload from aws-sdk in react, and I have already configured CORS of the server like this:

```
{
         "CORSRules": [
            {
                "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
                "AllowedMethods": ["GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "POST"],
                "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
                "ExposeHeaders": ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]
            }
       ]
    }
```

I get always this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx.s3.sbg.io.cloud.ovh.net/videos/fef70a9a-c9ca-4606-8a97-edfda0f26115' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Whereas if I use the ALLOW CORS extension on browser, everything works